# Chrome 59.0.3071.115 suddenly drains battery (approx 1% every 5min)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, google-chrome

A month ago I noticed that my new macbook pro 2015 battery drains in a few hours (2-4). I started testing which app is suddenly consuming its battery and found out it was Chrome.

When it is open (current version is 59.0.3071.115), battery drops in front of your eyes. Like 1% in 5 minutes.

Nothing unusual happens on my side. I use Chrome just like I have been using it for the past 8 months on this machine (sometimes have 10 tabs open at the same time). But the bottom line is that the same behaviour with Chrome did not drain battery 2 months ago, and it started 1 month ago and is still draining it.

I am using macbook on battery and only recharge when I am around 5%. So macbook was not connected to the power all the time (in case someone may think that constant connection to the power could have damaged the battery).

Anyone experiencing the same issue? any cure to it?

I switched to Safari in the meantime to recuperate things.

Comment: Chrome is notorious for being fast but being terrible on battery life.  There are videos of this on youtube.